# Codeigniter Remember Me Functionality with autocomplete = 'new-password'

Tags: php, codeigniter

In remember me functionality i am storing data on cookie :

```
setcookie("password",$this->input->post('password'),time);
```

& used cookie in HTML with value attribute

```
<input type="text" name="password" value="<?php if($this->input->cookie('password')) echo $this->input->cookie('password');?>" autocomplete="new-password">
```

this code in working fine but if the cookie is empty that time password field from the **inspect element** not display **value attribute**. But When cookie is set in input field then the **password is visible in inspect element**... **Even without this functionality when browser set the cookie in input field with yellow background then also the password value attibute is not visible in inspect element**

**I want to hide the value attribute(password) from the inspect element when cookie is not empty. Or how can i set the form field value like browser without setting value attribute in input field**

Comment: *Remember Me* usually saves your session, not password. It's insecure to save plain password

Comment: @Justinas Ref : https://phppot.com/php/php-login-script-with-remember-me/ 
I was stored data in cookie.. But the main question is how can i set the form fields like browser (When browser set the fields then value of it wont be visible in inspect element)

Comment: You can't. It's browser that doing it, not JS. Also your link has valid code. But it's not secure.

Comment: Indeed, there are plenty of examples of *what not to do* on the internet... saving plaintext passwords is one of them. I would be scared to use a site that did this, and would probably run far away from it.